# PyAutoGui screenshots are black

Tags: python, screenshot, fedora, pyautogui

Screenshots taken from PyAutoGui are black.

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.screenshot('ss1.png')
pag.screenshot('ss2.png', region=(0,0, 200, 100))
```

I'm using Fedora

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) the screenshot function needs `scrot` to be installed on a Linux system to work.

In Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install scrot
```

In Arch:

```
sudo pacman -S scrot
```

And if you need to use confidence in your image location you need a opencv

In Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install opencv python3-opencv
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm having this blackscreenshot issue as well using Arch.

EDIT:
I have discovered what the issue is, wayland is not supported with pyautogui. Even with scrot installed. you can disable wayland as a workaround to get the screenshots to work

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's question